# changes in 2 dependent variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Deformation $ \delta $  and stress $ \sigma$ depend on  parameters
$r$ and $t$, varyjng inversely as $ r^3 \, t $ and $ r \, t  $ respectively.  In order to reduce $ \delta $ from 6 to 4 and also $ \sigma$ from 45 to 30, to what values should $(r,t)$ be changed from their given starting values  (72,5) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $\delta = C_1/(r^3t)$ and $\sigma = C_2/(rt)$.  Therefore
$$\frac{\delta_2}{\delta_1} = \frac{r_1^3t_1}{r_2^3t_2}$$ and
$$\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1} = \frac{r_1t_1}{r_2t_2}$$
We have
$$ \frac{2}{3} = \frac{r_1^3t_1}{r_2^3t_2} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \frac{2}{3} = \frac{r_1t_1}{r_2t_2}$$
So $r_1$ must be kept the same and $t_1$ changed to $(3/2)t_1$.